# Initializer not a constant. Malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I am writing this in C:

```
char *IP = malloc(12 * sizeof(char));
```

But I get "Initializer is not a constant

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't say anything by seeing just a single line of code!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the line of code you've posted. Check the error message again and make sure you've got the right line.

Comment: You can initialize variables in global scope only with constant expressions. So, you can not use an arbitrary function invocation there. This is what compiler says.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to assign a value to a variable outside of any function. In this case, you can only assign constant values, which are not the result of function calls or operations. For example, you can do

```
int i = 3;
```

but not

```
int i = pow(2, 2);
```

For what you want to do, you can declare the variable in the global scope, but then assign a value in the `main`.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
char *IP;
...
IP = malloc(12 * sizeof(char));//in main
```

Comment: It seems to me that this does answer the question ("try this" is just a figure of speech)